# jquery 1 vs jquery 3 legacy browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that jquery 2.x is not supporting legacy browsers and if I want to support those really old IEs I need to use jquery 1.x. And what about jquery 3.x? Is it supporting legacy browsers? Is it based on jquery 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: Have you read the various jQuery blog posts about jQuery 3? E.g. https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/

Comment: Have a look at the [browser-support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) page of Jquery: `If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.`

Comment: I didnt have time to read ALL those release notes, so I asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE8 is no longer supported in jQuery 3

> If you read the jQuery 3.0 alpha blog post, you might remember that we announced something we called “jQuery Compat”. You can forget that. On January 12, Microsoft dropped support for IE8, IE9, and IE10. We’re not going to go that far just yet, but we are dropping support for IE8. And with IE8, so goes jQuery Compat, gone before we even released a final version. There will only be one jQuery from now on!

https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/

From another blog post

> First is jQuery 3.0, which supports modern browsers and environments from IE9 forward.

https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/

If you want to support legacy browsers, you should use jQuery 1.x.x instead

Comment: So jquery 3 supports all browser except IE 8? So jquery 3 supports more browsers than jquery 2 and less browsers than jquery 1? Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure which browsers jQuery 2 supports but I know for a fact 3 supports from IE9 up. This is from jQuery themselves